# Insert command with where clause and like clause

Tags: sql

I have a table called 'LOGIN' with the following columns: `username`, `password`, `dept_id`, `address`, `name` and `designation`. I want the user to be added only by the head of that particular department to which the employee belongs. The employees in same dept will have the same id type like VBA2034, VBA2305 and so on.

I am addling what to and how to do it. I tried using like as below but its throwing an error. I searched for the INSERT command with WHERE clause and LIKE clause but didn't get exactly how to do it. Is it ok if I write the query like below.

```
INSERT INTO 
   `login`(`username`, `password`, `dept_id`, `address`, `type`, `name`) 
   VALUES ('VBA5013',123,'VBA','nehru vihar','customer executive','mr kuwara') 
where 'username' like 'VBA----' 
and 'dept_id' like 'VBA';
```

Comment: The idea is that you're trying to `INSERT` information in the tables, not extract it. Thus, you don't need filter clauses if you already know what information you are inserting. If you would insert information from a `SELECT` statement, then `WHERE` clauses would be relevant. In the current format, you know exactly what information goes in which column, so no filtering is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WHERE` only applies to `SELECT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`. An `INSERT` creates a new record, using `WHERE` doesn't make any sense if there's nothing yet.

Answer (score 0):

Filter the values before composing the INSERT statement.